# MySQL Data Access Layer: How do you store your queries?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, visual-studio-2010, data-access-layer

I've been building this project as the solo dev for a while, and while I'm comfortable in the front end and middle tier, I don't really think I'm doing the database the way I should be, and the reason why is because I simply don't really know of any other way. The way I'm currently getting data is by testing out queries in my MySQL workbench and copying and pasting the SQL as a string literal into a method that makes a call to the DB, pulls the data and hydrates my objects.

This hasn't really been a problem until recently, when I had to create a monster of a query and it got me thinking that maybe there's a better way to do this. I don't have a formal DAL separated out, so I know there's room for improvement there, but I was curious about what the correct way would be to store SQL strings. I assume there is a tool somewhere built into VS10 where I can manipulate and work with SQL as SQL instead of as a string.

Comment: Sounds like a good case for MyBatis: http://mybatis.org/dotnet.html

Comment: visual studio has a Entity Framework that might be useful, but it add a big layer of ORM complexity .

Comment: i'm just really looking for a place to drop files, maybe with an extension of `.sql` and be able to reference them in code somehow. is that possible? maybe i can even pass in objects whose properties and methods could be referenced?

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this in stored procedures. That will basically format and store your query. You set parameters that are passed in from your code, then read out the results.

Example:

The C# method:

```
private void SetNote()
{
    const string sql = "sp_SelectControllerNoteByID";
    using (var conn = MocSystem.GetMocDbConnection())
    {
        using (var comm = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ControllerNoteID", ControllerNoteId));
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (var rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        CommentText = rdr["NoteText"].ToString();
                        _commentor = new User(new Guid(rdr["NoteAuthor"].ToString()));
                        CommentDate = (DateTime)rdr["NoteDate"];
                        MocRequestId = (int)rdr["MocRequestID"];
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HasError = true;
                ErrorMessage += "\nThere was a problem building the note: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The stored procedure on the DBMS (sql server in this example):

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_SelectControllerNoteByID]
    @ControllerNoteID   int
AS
    SELECT
        ControllerNoteID,
        NoteText,
        NoteDate,
        NoteAuthor,
        MocRequestID
    FROM
        ControllerNotes
    WHERE
        ControllerNoteID = @ControllerNoteID
```

So here we call the stored procedure which in this case is just a simple select statement, then we read it out into an object via ADO. Now, this way, you can modify your query without recompiling. Unless you add parameters, in which case you'll have to update those in your code as well.